# mvc call controller from jquery with parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to call MVC controller method from Jquery. Below is my code but it is not working

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult singleValue(string valuetoset)
    {
        //Code
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$('#User').live('change', function (e) {
    var userValue = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;

 $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/singleValue",
        type: 'GET',
         data: { valuetoset: userGuideValue },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

I need to pass valuetoset argument, but it always going as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change url ajax method should be like this:

```
url:'@Url.Action("Home", "singleValue")',
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` parameter needs to be in JSON format. There are a number of ways to do so, here's one:

```
var myData = {};
myData["valuetoset"] = userValue;
```

Here, `valuetoset` corresponds to your controller action parameter. Then, your `data` declaration should be as follows:

```
data: myData
```

Or, you could just include `userValue` in your URL if your routes are set up correctly since this is a GET action:

```
url: host + "/Home/singleValue/" + userValue
```